# Loop through array of images in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, loops

I'm trying to loop through an array of images but can't seem to get past image 2.

The array should also loop back to 1 when the last image has passed...

```
    var WorkArray = new Array('work/01.png', 'work/02.png', 'work/03.png', 'work/04.png');

var nelements = WorkArray.length;

preload_image_object = new Image();
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<=nelements; i++)  {
    preload_image_object.src = WorkArray[i];
    }

function cC() {
    var nelements = WorkArray.length;
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<=nelements; i++)  {
    nelements = WorkArray[i];
    }
    document.getElementById("work").style.backgroundImage="url('"+WorkArray[i]+"')";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the current file and use modulo to run in cyclic manner.

It will look something like that:

```
var WorkArray = new Array('work/01.png', 'work/02.png', 'work/03.png', 'work/04.png');
var currentImage = 0

function nextImage(){
 currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % WorkArray.length;
 document.getElementById("work").style.backgroundImage="url('"+WorkArray[currentImage]+"')";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting nelements with the current element of the loop:

```
nelements = WorkArray[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should fix your loops:

```
var WorkArray = new Array('work/01.png', 'work/02.png', 'work/03.png', 'work/04.png');
var preload_image_object = new Image();

/* Lets get rid of `nelements`, as its just confusing. Get the length here. 
 * If, for performace reasons you want to use elements, the best way is to reverse
 * aka for(var i = WorkArray.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
 * Also, its simpler to declare the var in your for-loop itself instead of outside of it.
 */
for(var i = 0; i <= WorkArray.length; i++){
    preload_image_object.src = WorkArray[i];
}
```

Also, again for simplifications sake, your application of the background-image could be done inside your for loop as well, and can be made to look cleaner with some spaces and omitting the `'` inside your `url()`:

```
document.getElementById("work").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + WorkArray[i] + ")";
```